# AllShortestPath returns more relations than needed

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to list all shortest paths between `Darjeeling` and `Sandakphu`. Whilst query results in proper number of nodes (3 hops), it also shows relationships that would result in longer path (4 hops) such as `Darjeeling>Tumbling>Gairibus>BhikeBhanja>Sandakphu`.

Here's my query

```
MATCH graphView = allShortestPaths(({name: "Darjeeling"})-[*]->({name: "Sandakphu"})) RETURN graphView
```

And here's the graph result

[image]

**How do I modify the query so that the unnecessary relations are gone?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `allShortestPaths` function only gives you paths with the **same length** !

But, if you run it on the browser and display the result as a graph, the browser will display all paths, but also **all the links between those elements**.

You can disable this feature, by disabled the `Connect result nodes` checkbox on the browser configuration panel.

If you want to be sure of the result, just take a look at the `table` result (not the graph).